# VueJs Address Bar

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, dashboard, address-bar

**Hi friends,**

**The company I work for has a website with an Admin Dashboard. Pages that users can use according to their authorization are listed in the menu. Beautiful so far. However, there is a problem. The person can reach the pages that he cannot see in the menu at the moment, without authorization, from the address bar, by entering the link of the page. How can I prevent access to unauthorized pages from the Address Bar by redirecting them from one place? I don't want to check each page individually. This doesn't make sense. For example, a component with the message "You are not authorized to view this page" may be displayed or automatically redirected to the home page.**

**I'm waiting for your help. Thanks.**

Comment: Is it possible to show some code? Tell us what did you try, what worked and/or what didnt? There are plenty of solutions that can be suggested, on different levels of the application.

Comment: @Zarko I don't have a code block on this topic. But what I want to do is this.Users have groups defined in the database. And these groups are mapped to specific pages.That is, there are certain pages that people can access by groups. What I want to do is to prevent access to the page by entering the link of the unauthorized pages in the address bar of the user logged into the system. I don't know how to do this. More precisely.I can,but the way I know is to check the window.location on each page separately.I wanted to know how I can control this on all pages with a single code block or method.

Answer (score 0):

**You will need to use a global router navigation guard/hook called `beforeEach` - as explained in multiple tutorials:**

1. **https://css-tricks.com/protecting-vue-routes-with-navigation-guards/**
2. **https://www.permify.co/post/implementing-role-based-access-control-in-vue-js**